# When I call this AlertDialog it came empty

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

When I call this Alert Dialog it came empty, for some reason the view about is not showing, instead of that it showing me only the dialog with App name and the word "About" but the view is now displaying at all :

```
public class AboutBox {
static String VersionName(Context context) {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),0).versionName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
public static void Show(Activity callingActivity) {
    //Use a Spannable to allow for links highlighting
    SpannableString aboutText = new SpannableString("Version " + VersionName(callingActivity)+ "nn"
            + callingActivity.getString(R.string.about));
    //Generate views to pass to AlertDialog.Builder and to set the text
    View about;
    TextView tvAbout;
    try {
        //Inflate the custom view
        LayoutInflater inflater = callingActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        about = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aboutbox, (ViewGroup) callingActivity.findViewById(R.id.aboutView));
        tvAbout = (TextView) about.findViewById(R.id.aboutText);
    } catch(InflateException e) {
        //Inflater can throw exception, unlikely but default to TextView if it occurs
        about = tvAbout = new TextView(callingActivity);
    }
    //Set the about text
    tvAbout.setText(aboutText);
    // Now Linkify the text
    Linkify.addLinks(tvAbout, Linkify.ALL);
    //Build and show the dialog
    new AlertDialog.Builder(callingActivity)
            .setTitle("About " + callingActivity.getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .setView(about)
            .show();    //Builder method returns allow for method chaining
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You might be getting an exception and `about = new TextView(callingActivity);`  invoked which is an empty TextView added to AlertDialog.

Comment: No I am not getting any exception, the textView created successes and I can get its text in Log.

Comment: It may also be theme related. If you are dynamically creating a TextView and default text color is white you may not be able to see text.

Comment: my bad ;) the color was white.
the problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `callingActivity` with `getApplicationContext()` during calling `getString()` like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(callingActivity)
            .setTitle("About " + getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
            .setView(about)
            .show();
```

Comment: It does not matter which context you use for getting resources, but it's better to use getApplicationContext() since an object my outlive the Activity that has Activity's context  and cause Activity to leak.

Comment: I don’t think it is a problem as I can get the application name successfully. My main problem is in About view. I Log all string that pass to About view and I can see it, but it doesn’t appear in the dialog.